# Alterar Active Profiles Spring em tempo de execução

Tags: spring, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

Geralmente utilizo esse trecho de código para definir o *profile* da aplicação

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>production</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso em tempo de execução através de um *controller* ?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível fazer programaticamente via java. 
Use da seguinte maneira:

```java
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("container");
```

Onde o ctx é o seu contexto do spring.
Fonte: http://diarmuidmoloney.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/spring-environments/

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Vou fazer e teste e volto aqui para contar. Vlw